# How to sum the minutes of each activity in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The column "activitie_time_enter" has the times.

The column "activitie_still" indicates the type of activity.

The column "activitie_walking" indicates the other type of activity.

Table example:

```
activitie_time_enter | activitie_still | activitie_walking
           17:30:20  |        Still    | 
           17:31:32  |        Still    |
           17:32:24  |                 |  Walking  
           17:33:37  |                 |  Walking  
           17:34:20  |        Still    | 
           17:35:37  |        Still    |
           17:45:13  |        Still    |
           17:50:23  |        Still    |
           17:51:32  |                 |  Walking
```

What I need is to sum up the total minutes for each activity separately.
Any suggestions or solution?

Comment: Please show what results you want.  It is not clear what the values should be.

Comment: Using the example table.

The still activity would result in a value of approximately 18 minutes.
The walking activity would result in a value of 1 minute and a few seconds.

Comment: I need the total minutes or seconds on each activity.

Comment: how do you calculate "still activity would result in a value of approximately 18 minutes?"  When does an activity begin, and when does it end?  Do you merely take `17:50:23 - 17:30:20 = X` to calculate `still` period, then `X - (17:33:37 - 17:32:24)` to remove `walking` duration?  It seems the design of this data needs some improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the duration for each activity (the `with` CTE) and then do conditional sum.

```sql
with t as
(
 select
   *, lead(activitie_time_enter) over (order by activitie_time_enter) - activitie_time_enter as duration
 from _table 
)
select 
    sum (duration) filter (where activitie_still = 'Still') as total_still, 
    sum (duration) filter (where activitie_walking = 'Walking') as total_walking 
from t;

/** Result:
total_still|total_walking|
-----------+-------------+
   00:19:16|     00:01:56|
*/
```

BTW do you really need two columns (`activitie_still` and `activitie_walking`)? Only one `activity` column with those values will do. This will allow more activities (Running, Sleeping, Working etc.) w/o having to change the table structure.

Comment: Thank you! I believe it's the solution, soon I'll do a more robust test and give you feedback :)